# My laptop works too slow when it is moved/vibrated

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, troubleshooting, fan, nvidia-graphics-card

Recently my laptop's (HP envy 15) fan works too loud and gets warmer than before. When the laptop is moved, the laptop works slow for 30-90 seconds then it turns to normal, especially if any video is playing, it takes longer to recover. I already cleaned the fan and interior of the laptop and I feel the evacuated hot air flow.

The laptop has NVIDIA GT 750M card, and sometime I see a notice that kernel driver of it is recovered.

I wonder if it is fan, graphic card, or another problem related problem? Has anyone experienced such problem before?

Comment: The fact the display driver is crashing should be a concern.  What driver version do you have installed currently?  The laptop working a little harder when its moved isn't a huge concern, the display driver crashing is, but you don't seem to know if its actually warmer then before or not.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is installed, the device manager says the driver works properly. The installed driver version is 9.18.13.3165

Comment: You should update the driver, it its extremely out of date, and likely part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I received my new fan and replaced it with the old one. All the problem is gone. I guess the old fan was functioning but not enough to cool or had problem with the temperature feedback. Overheat should have effected the performance of the graphic card. When I watch video or steam, RAM should be involved rather than HDD. According to the NVDIA control center, it has the latest driver.

Thanks for the answers and additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the movement slowdown and high temps are two separate issues.

First things first, have you checked that you're not running anything which eats up CPU or GPU cycles? Bitcoin miner malwares come to mind.

This may be unlikely but movement induced slowdown could be a safety mechanism to protect HDD. I don't have the laptop in question but my old Lenovo had a program which delayed HDD writes after a smallest shock. Check if you are running such and disable it. You could have that preinstalled even if the laptop came with SSD drive.

Also, since you're running hot and performance is poor: is the CPU throttling due overheating? If you have Intel CPU, you can check that with [XTU](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-boards-software-extreme-tuning-utility.html). CPU overheating could be caused by poorly attached fan assembly or poorly coded malware.

Answer (score 1):

HP has a system known as 3D Driveguard that will limit the damage that can be done to the hard drive when the laptop is moved. This will almost certainly reduce the performance of the system while it is being moved.

This is one of a group of systems known as [Active hard-drive protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_hard-drive_protection)

If you want the performance and do not mind the risk of hard drive failure due to dropping the laptop at a bad moment then you should be able to disable the protection from the BIOS screen or within the Driveguard utility.

Apparently it may also be named differently, HP cannot make up its mind what to call it. Look for `3D DriveGuard`, `HP Mobile Data Protection System 3D` and `ProtectSmart Hard Drive Protection` in your list of applications.

If you cannot find it in your list of applications the you should be able to download it from the support pages for your laptop. If there is a utility on those support pages it should allows you to disable this protection.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Its worth pointing out that the other OEM's also have similar services which are installed through their utility programs.  One additional way would be to use a SSD this would allow you to disable the service and not worry about the damage that might happen while the device is being moved if the service was diabled with a mechanical drive.  SSD has no mechanical parts, in theory a SSD could be dropped from a reasonable height, and unless one of the ICB physically broke the device would still work.  I don't suggest you test this though.